# PegJS: How to match a phrase in surrounding text

Tags: parsing, peg, pegjs

I'm tryingto make a parser with [PegJS](http://pegjs.majda.cz/)

I'm trying to parse something like this..

`I would like to email john@gmail.com today or tomorrow.`

How would you make a parser that matches on certain phrases, like `email john@gmail.com` and throw away the surrounding characters and space (if they exists).

The problem I keep having is that is the matchers consume the whole line, phrase and all—before more detailed matchers have a chance to go.

Also, can someone break down `negative look aheads`? (the mechanics and there syntax)
It seems they are the answer, but I'm having a hard time find information on them.

Thank you,
Geo.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out. This work.

```
find_tokens = 
 (!tokens .)* 
 result: (token: tokens { return token; })
 (!tokens .)*
 { return result; }
```